# Finding character count in string using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I am required to use recursion to determine the number of occurrences of a certain character in a given string. Now the non-recursive function is very simple. But, when trying to use recursion, I am getting an error when my program runs

```
short f_r(string, char);
int main()
{
    string str;
    char c;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline(cin,str);
    cout << "Enter a character: ";
    cin >> c;
    cout << "\nString: " << str << endl;
    cout << f_r(str,c) << endl;


    return 0;

}

short f_r(string str, char c)
{

    int pos = 0;
    pos = str.find(c, pos);
    if (pos >  str.length()) return 0;
    else
    {
        int count = 0;
        count++;
        pos++;
        return count + f_r(str,c);
    }

}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: By the looks of it, `f_r` has no viable break condition. It will always find the first char, and recurse with the same input data.

Comment: if (pos!=string::npos)

Comment: `std::string::find` returns `std::string::npos` when a value isn't found.  You should test explicitly against that to decide if it failed to find something.

Comment: @RetiredNinja and Jekyll Absolutely. Even if that is fixed, I don't see how this doesn't recurse infinitely.

Comment: he should call the recursive function with a substr, or passing the actual pos at least to the recursive function and then searching from there.....

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh yeah, you're totally correct about it never ending because `pos` never increases, but the unsigned/signed issue could be another source of problems.

Comment: @Jekyll Yup, and on that line, he should be calling `std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), c)` and not doing the recursion *at all*, but if this is an academic assignment I see the utility in it (kind of).

Comment: @WhozCraig I think it was an homework as he wrote 'I am required to use recursion'...

Comment: @Jekyll yeah, I concur. I can think of better academic exercises than this for recursion, but at least this is grasp-able. Not entirely horrid for a first attempt. Hope he didn't spend too much time on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem Analysis**

Your fundamental problems in your implementation are:

- Failure to use the proper data type for the discovered position
- Incorrect conditional to terminate the recursion
- Incorrect recursion parameters (you're passing the same parameters).

**Solution**

That said, this function is simpler than you may think:

```
std::size_t f_r(const std::string& s, char c)
{
    std::string::size_type pos = s.find(c);
    return (pos == std::string::npos) ? 0 : (1 + f_r(s.substr(pos+1), c));
}
```

Note the following:

- Uses `std::string::size_type` for the position calculation
- Terminates the recursion if no value is returned by comparing against `std::string::npos`, returning `0` as the result of that final recursion invocation.
- Passes a substring of the original as a parameter to the recursed call. This substring includes all remaining characters *passed* the discovered location in `pos`.

---

**Non Recursive Solution**

I realize you're tasked with doing this recursively, but I wanted to make sure you knew the way to do it iteratively without having to write the loop yourself. The C++ standard library includes an algorithm called [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) that does *exactly* what this does, but with a single pass, no sub-allocations like those delivered from `substr()`, and no recursion at all:

```
std::size_t f_r(const std::string& s, char c)
{
    return std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), c);
}
```

and yes, it does make the very reason for `f_r()` somewhat pointless.

Answer (score 1):

This "program" has too many problems to offer a quick fix. For starters, consider the following:

- Your "recursion" keeps calling the function with the same state over and over again, so ultimately you'll blow the stack.
- `string.find()` returns an `npos` in case of not found character.

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` branch keeps passes the entire string into the recursive call.  This will continue until the stack overflows.  You need to only pass the part of the string after the first instance of `c`.  You can do this by changing

```
return count + f_r(str,c);
```

to

```
str = str.substr(pos, str.size()-pos);
return count + f_r(str,c);
```

Note also that since `count` is always `1`, this block would be simpler as

```
pos++;
str = str.substr(pos, str.size()-pos);
return 1 + f_r(str,c);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to add `pos` as an argument to `f_r()` instead of doing `substr`?

Comment: @PeteBecker lol. Flashback a *long* time ago from my op-sys graduate course. The instructor was fairly blunt: "1. Architect an efficient design. 2. If your project doesn't work, you fail the course, and I don't care how efficient your design is."

Answer (score 0):

I would write the function using a static variable.

```
std::string::size_type f_r( const std::string &s, char c )
{
    static std::string::size_type pos;

    pos = s.find( c, pos );

    return ( pos == std::string::npos ? pos = 0 : ( ++pos, 1 + f_r( s, c ) ) );
}
```