# Find count of character occurrences in array using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm pretty new with recursion. I need to write two functions. So far I wrote one, which entitles finding the length of a string. However, the second one, which is: finding the repeating character in an array is proving to be very difficult. I have scoured the web trying to find examples, I have been doing a lot of reading but nothing so far. So if you could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you

```
//length( ) -- this function is sent a null terminated array of characters.  
    //The function returns the length of the "string".    
    long slength (const char ntca[])
        {
            int length = 0;

            if (ntca[length] == '\0'){
                return 0;
            }
            else{
                return  slength(ntca+1)+1;
            }
        }

        //countall( ) -- This function is sent a null terminated array of characters 
        //and a single character.  The function returns the number of times the character 
        //appears in the array.

        long countall (const char ntca[],char letter){

            int position = 0;
            int counter = 0;
            long length = slength(ntca);

            if (length == 0)
                return 0;

            else if (ntca[position]==letter)
                return 1 + countall(ntca-1,letter);
            else 
                return countall(ntca,letter);


        }
```

Comment: Note that I would write a recursive string length but it seems the length function wants to read `long slength(char const* s) { return *s? 1 + slength(): 0; }`

Comment: You're close. Notice how in the first function, you're moving one character ahead in the string, each time? You need to do the same in `countall()`, both in the case where `letter` is matched, and in the case where it's not. In one case, you're currently backing up (into unknown territory); in the other case, you're just calling `countall` on the same character over and over.

Comment: You certainly don't want to compute the length of the string for the second function! If the string isn't empty add 1 if the front character is the requested  letter to the result of `countall()` with the tail of the string: `long countall(char const* s, char l) { return (*s == l) + (*s? countall(s + 1, l): 0); }`. Your error is that you either stick on the same position or even go backwards!

Comment: [Is this for some class you're all taking, and hitting up SO for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965083/finding-character-count-in-string-using-recursion). also, I'm not really seeing much C++ in this language-wise. It is certainly *valid* C++, but equally valid C. If you're tasked with a recursive solution that uses no C++ standard library features, can you at least use C-library features, such as [`strchr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr)? No bigger if not, just curious.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code:

```
long countall(const char *ptr, char letter)
{
    if(!*ptr) return 0; //base case
    return (*ptr == letter) + countall(ptr + 1, letter);
}
```

The base case of recursion is when function meets the end of the string. For an `empty string` and any letter the `answer is 0`.

If string is not empty, we `add 1` to the result of `recursive call on shorter string` if and only if the `current char matches letter`.